# If cell is blank then make variable equivalent to any value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with 3 List Boxes. Each List Box is populated by a list that is created, each List Box contains a "Blank" data point. I am trying to write a script that goes:

```
For lpRows = 1 to 100
  For lpColumns = 1 to 8
     If ListBox1 = "" and ListBox2 = "Val" And ListBox3 = "Var" Then
         Sheets(RndmSheet).Cells(lprows,lpcolumns) = Sheets(DiffSheet).Cells(lprows,lpColumns)
else
end if
```

However, my code isn't working because VBA is simply searching for a blank cell, where I would prefer it to return any value that contains both ListBox2 and ListBox3, but Listbox1 would be irrelevant.

Is there an easy way to use a wildcard to achieve what I want or will I need to simply make a rather large nested if statements to handle this?

Comment: I apologize for forgetting the next lpRows and next lpColumns in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

I just added in an if statement

```
if sheets(rndmsheet).cell(lpRows,lpColumns) = "" then
   VarCell = Sheets(rndmsheet).cell(lprows,lpcolumns)
end if
```

Sorry if that doesn't really make sense.